# Можно ли с помощью Django-filer в модели создать папку?

Tags: python, django

Могу ли я к модели привязать папку с фото?  Тоесть я написал модель в которой место для фота или файла я могу поставить несколько файлов

Comment: Параметр `upload_to` для `FileField`?

Comment: Мне нужно. Возможно ли это. При написание модели я могу поставить фото, а могу ли я поставить папку

Comment: Что значит "место для фота"? У вас в модели поле типа FilerImageField?

Comment: Да на место ключа FilerImageField. Извините за неправильно поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Можно использовать `ForeignKey` на `filer.models.Folder` или `FilerFolderField`.